# Return malloc struct gets freed from memory

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return, dynamic-arrays

So I compiled this code both at the terminal with MinGW and it was originally compiled in Visual Studio both not showing any sign of wrong-doing.
It is a code for Dynamic Arrays and after hours of debugging in VS I found that when I malloc another structure and array, copy all the integers and then point the old array to the new one it won't remain in the memory. Also the size and threshold are not pointers, but shouldn't they not be freed from memory just like the structure? The code is as follows. I also have it available (a bit changed) at my GitHub [here](https://github.com/LeoVen/EEP/blob/master/DataStructures/DataStructures/C/Structures/DArray.c)

I'm probably doing something really stupid, but I've burned my mind into this and can't get to any conclusions. I resisted asking it at stackoverflow (because most of my mistakes are really dumb) but after hours of debugging I gave up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct DArray {
    int *array;     // Array of integers
    int size;       // Actual Size
    int maxSize;    // Maximum size.
    bool threshold; // maxSize / 2
} DArray;

DArray * getDArray(int maxSize);
int pushValueDArray(DArray *array, int value);
int popValueDArray(DArray *array);
int displayDArray(DArray *array);
int checkSize(DArray *array);

DArray * getDArray(int maxSize)
{
    if (maxSize < 0) {
        printf("\nFATAL ERROR\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    DArray *newArr = (DArray *)malloc(sizeof(DArray));
    newArr->size = 0;
    newArr->maxSize = maxSize;
    newArr->threshold = false;
    newArr->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxSize);
    return newArr;
}

int pushValueDArray(DArray *array, int value)
{
    checkSize(array);
    array->array[array->size] = value;
    (array->size)++;
    return 0;
}

int popValueDArray(DArray *array)
{
    checkSize(array);
    array->array[array->size] = 0;
    (array->size)--;
    return 0;
}

int displayDArray(DArray *array)
{
    int i;
    if (array->size == 0) {
        printf("\n[ Empty ] \n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n[ ");
    for (i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array->array[i]);
    }
    printf("nil ]\n");
    return 0;
}

int checkSize(DArray *array)
{
    int i;
    if (array->size > array->maxSize / 2) array->threshold = true;
    if (array->size >= array->maxSize - 1) {
        // Grow
        DArray *nArray = getDArray(array->maxSize * 2);
        DArray *kill = array;
        for (i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
            nArray->array[i] = array->array[i];
        }
        nArray->size = array->size;
        nArray->threshold = false;
        array = nArray;
        free(kill);
        return 0; // OK
    }
    else if (array->threshold && array->size < array->maxSize / 2) {
        // Shrink
        DArray *nArray = getDArray(array->maxSize / 2 + 1);
        DArray *kill = array;
        for (i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
            nArray->array[i] = array->array[i];
        }
        nArray->size = array->size;
        nArray->threshold = false;
        array = nArray;
        free(kill);
        return 0; // OK
    }
    else {
        // OK
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    DArray *array = getDArray(100);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        pushValueDArray(array, i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        popValueDArray(array);
    }
    displayDArray(array);

    printf("\nsize %d", array->size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int checkSize(DArray *array)` but you reassign `array` locally. it doesn't change it outside the function, a classic duplicate.

Comment: and the `checkSize` name is misleading. It checks and (unsuccessfully) increases the size. It should have the pointer of pointer as argument (or return the new pointer, since the return value is always 0): `int adjustSize(DArray **array)` or `DArray *ajustSize(DArray *array)`

Comment: Thanks! So many array variables confused me. And thanks for the tip about the function name.